# Wrapping floated block elements

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FK3cd/3/

What I want is for the `<li>`'s to break to the next line when its width is wider than the fixed container. In other words, instead of pushing the container wider, I want the `<li>` to wrap to the next line. Eg. something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FK3cd/4/ (except without the explicit width)

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript, or does this need to be pure CSS?

Comment: Preferably just CSS. But if a pure CSS solution is not possible, a JS solution is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you're using this, you could wrap the list in its own `<div>`, which is `position: absolute`. That causes the inner `<div>` to collapse to the width of the parent, and as long as you don't mess with the `top` and `left`, it will stay at its current position.

But this removes your list from the document flow and may break other layout further down the page.

[Check out this fiddle for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/YfHM5/1/) Notice that the yellow background doesn't include the list.

Comment: I think you got the wrong link for the fiddle. This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/FK3cd/6/ But as you said, it would break the layout. I'll mark this as the correct answer if there aren't any other answers.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to save the fiddle before I copied the URL. I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible within just CSS, as you don't want to set an explicit width, the container size will adjust to the content.